# Dynamically Switching between styles files pathes

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I want to replace style file with the one determined when executing **ng serve -c=customeTheme**
I don't get any error but the styles of customeTheme doesn't get applied;

I know that i can get the same behavior by setting variable in environment.ts and acessing it in appComponent then make our condition but I need to do this using angular.json configuration and without writing the style path in    **ng serve -c=customeTheme --styles= src/../..scss**

Angular CLI: 10.2.4
Node: 14.18.1

```
{
  "projects": {
    "redux-store": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "assets": [---],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/scss/defaultTheme"
              ]
            },..
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "defaultTheme": {
              "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": [
                  "src/scss/defaultTheme/"
                ]
              }
            },
            "customeTheme": {
              "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": [
                  "src/scss/customeTheme/"
                ]
              }
            
          }    
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "redux-store:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "defaultTheme": {
              "browserTarget": "redux-store:build:defaultTheme"
            },
            "customeTheme": {
              "browserTarget": "redux-store:build:customeTheme"
            }
          }
        },

  "defaultProject": "redux-store"
}
```

I've tried theses commands :
ng build -c=customeTheme